# Character search in C programming

Tags: c, pointers, search, character

have a function in a program that needs to search for a character in a string file. In main the string is declared and the value is set by user input like this:

```
char studentdata[40];
scanf("%s", &studentdata);
```

As part of the task, the user will always write the character '/' in the middle of the string, which will have to be found. My code for the search:

```
int i=0;
char z = '/';
while (studentData[i]!=z)
    {
        i++;
    }
```

studentData is a variable of the function declared as

```
char *studentData
```

The idea was that after the loop variable i contained the position of character z, but the program never comes out of the loop and crashes. It probably is a beginner mistake as I am new at this... Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you tried looking up strchr? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strchr.htm

Comment: `while (studentData[i] != z && studentData[i] != '\0')`

Comment: Suggest dropping `&` from `scanf("%s", &studentdata);` --> `scanf("%39s", studentdata);`

Comment: Just tried it and it returns a NULL pointer...

Comment: @PeterNagy: What does each of those "it"s refer to?

Comment: Also, don't you get a warning from your compiler, something like `'scanf' format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[40]'`? If so… don't ignore those warnings. They often tell you exactly what's wrong with your code. Even if _you_ don't understand them, you can post them here and others can immediately explain them to you, instead of having to guess what's wrong with your code or debug it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
scanf("%s", &studentdata);
```

try

```
scanf("%s", studentdata);
```

because `studentdata` is already a pointer.  Currently you are telling scanf to write the result to the place where the address of the pointer points, not to the place that the pointer points (this will overwrite the actual pointer, and probably adjacent memory, causing unpredictable behavior).

Also note the two comments from @chux that you can prevent your program from crashing if '/' is not found by:

Changing the loop to end when it encounters a null character:

```
while (studentData[i] != z && studentData[i] != '\0')
```

Allow only up to 39 characters of input from scanf (keeping the 40th for the null terminator):

```
scanf("%39s", studentdata);
```

Comment: It is possible to use the strcspn If you become the length of the string if the specified character is not found. E.g. `i=strcspn(studentData, "/");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: My guess is this is a homework assignment.  If so, the objective is probably to learn the thought process behind functions like `strcspn`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to pass student data to scanf() correctly.  Use:

```
scanf("%s", studentdata);
```

The way you have it, you're passing a pointer to a pointer.

It's always wise to use a `#define` for the size of an array.  You should add:

```
#define SDSIZE 40
```

and declare your array as:

```
char studentdata[SDSIZE];
```

This makes maintenance much easier.  You'll see that you need to use `SDSIZE` in more than one place below.  This way, if you need to change the size, you just change the `#define` rather than looking for everywhere this is used and changing them all.

To keep it from crashing, you need to bounds check your indexing variable, `i`.  To keep it from misbehaving, you need to also watch for a string termination character (null).  So, your loop should look like this:

```
while( studentdata[i] != z && studentdata[i] != 0 && ++i < SDSIZE );
```

Now, when the loop exits, `i` will contain the index where `z` was found, it will equal `SDSIZE` if it wasn't found, or the value at the index (`studentdata[i]`) will be null if it wasn't found.  Test like this:

```
if( SDSIZE == i || studentdata[i] == 0 )
    printf( "Not found\n" );
else
    // do what you need to do with the result here.
```

This should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Because `studentdata` is a pointer when you type `&studentdata` that means the address of the pointer.

So what you really want is the value:

```
scanf("%s", studentdata);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I changed the code as you guys suggested and now it does not crash. When I print out the results it is still not perfect, but probably there is some other mistake in the program which I wil ltry to figure out. Thanks for all the help, have a great day!